# How to purge level 1 and level 2 cache?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to know if it is possible to purge the level 1 cache in nhibernate?

What about level 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level 1 cache is more commonly refered to as the *session*.

Simply do

```
session.Clear()
```

You could also use `session.Evict(instanceToEvict)` to just evict selectively.